# Erro ao retornar data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Eae galera, beleza?

Estou com um problema aqui, tava funcionando tudo normalmente e do nada começou a da esse problema.

Segue abaixo a função:

```
function atualizaHoraServidor() {

    var dia = digital.getDate();
    var mes = digital.getMonth();
    var ano = digital.getFullYear();
    var horas = digital.getHours();
    var minutos = digital.getMinutes();
    var segundos = digital.getSeconds();

    // aumenta 1 segundo
    digital.setSeconds(segundos + 1);

    // acrescento zero
    if (dia <= 9) dia = "0" + dia;
    if (mes <= 9) mes = "0" + mes;
    if (mes == 0) mes = "0" + mes;
    if (horas <= 9) horas = "0" + horas;
    if (minutos <= 9) minutos = "0" + minutos;
    if (segundos <= 9) segundos = "0" + segundos;

    dispTime = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano + " " + horas + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos;
    $('#horarioServidor .horarioRelogio').text(dispTime);
    setTimeout("atualizaHoraServidor()", 1000); // chamo a função a cada 1 segundo

}
```

O que ocorre é que ele ta retornando a data dessa forma:

20/000/2017 16:08:26

O dia e hora ta certo, só ta dando problema no mês e ano. Ele fica atualizando direto no site, ou seja, fica correndo os segundos la....

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Alguma função que substitua o getMonth e getFullYear?

Não sei se estou errado, mas acredito que isso só ocorre para o mês de DEZEMBRO, mês anterior tava normal.

Comment: Gostaria de ver o que esta vindo nessa variável digital. De qualquer forma  eu tiraria a linha ´if (mes == 0) mes = "0" + mes;´

Comment: `var digital = new Date(<?php echo str_replace(':',', ', str_replace('/',', ', str_replace(' ',', ', $Hora_Servidor_MySQL))).', 0'; ?>);`

Comment: Tentei tirar essa linha mas não funcionou...

Comment: Tire a duas linhas que trata o mês para ver como fica formatada a variavel dispTime.

Comment: Só diminuiu os zeros, ficou assim: 20/0/2017 16:32:54

Comment: Mostre o que está vindo na variavel `$Hora_Servidor_MySQL`

Comment: `$Hora_Servidor_MySQL = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');`

Comment: A hora é exibida por uma div, dessa forma: `<div id="horarioServidor"><div class="horarioRelogio"></div></div>`

Comment: Sim, ele começa do zero até o 11, sendo 0 para janeiro e 11 para dezembro, isso eu vi na documento... Mas você diz alterar onde exatamente?

Comment: Tem que alterar o mês para subtraindo 1 antes de passar para `new Date()`, e alterar novamente incrementando 1 antes de passa o conteudo para a `div`, é mais facil seguir a solução do Pedro, caso não consiga, eu posto a resposta da forma que falei.

Comment: Pode me passar da forma q falou? Pois não consegui fazer da outra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você não precisa de tudo isso só pra formatar, você pode usar a função [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) e formatar usando o segundo parâmetro.

Já formatei como você deseja, mas da uma olhadinha na documentação que você entende.

```js
var dataAtual = new Date();
var options = {
  year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", second: '2-digit'
};
var dataFormatada = dataAtual.toLocaleDateString('pt-br', options);

console.log(dataFormatada);
```

Agora, como isso ficaria com seu código:

```
function atualizaHoraServidor() {
  var dispTime = formatarData(digital);

  $('#horarioServidor .horarioRelogio').text(dispTime);

  digital.setSeconds(digital.getSeconds() + 1);

  setTimeout("atualizaHoraServidor()", 1000);
}

function formatarData(data) {
  var options = {
    year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", second: '2-digit'
};
  return data.toLocaleDateString('pt-br', options);  
}
```

Comment: Rapaz, não tenho conhecimento nessa área então não vou saber aplicar no meu código rsrs...

Comment: Obrigado Pedro.. Mas me tira uma dúvida, eu acredito que isso esta ocorrendo apenas no mês de dezembro, por que nos meses anteriores ele mostrava a data normalmente... Será que faz sentido ou nada ver?

Comment: Analisando seu código, quando usa o `digital.getMonth()` deveria mostrar `11`, por que o Date do Javascript começa a contar do zero. Experimente dar um `console.log` na data que está vindo do servidor pra ver o que está mostrando.

Comment: Tentei utilizar o código que informou, e ele não retornou nada, ficou em branco..

Comment: Mostra algum erro no console? Debugou o código? Ficou em branco pode dizer muita coisa, fica difícil ajudar. =/

Comment: No console, apareceu o seguinte: TypeError: ({}) is not a function e ReferenceError: formatarData is not defined

Comment: Corrigido o código da uma olhada, mas a mensagem já diz tudo o que estava ocorrendo. =/

Comment: Só trocou o formatar por formatarData data né? Eu cheguei a fazer isso, sério mesmo, mas ficou em branco do mesmo jeito huahuahua.

Comment: Agora: TypeError: data is undefined

Comment: A variável que você está passando para a função `formatarData` está com valor `undefined`. Ou seja, `digital` está `undefined`.

Comment: Consegui corrigir, porém ta aparecendo a data dessa forma: 20/01/2017 17:57:58

Comment: A variável digital ta com o valor correto agora, pelo menos no código fonte ele exibe a data correta, mas ele ta imprimindo para o mês seguinte....

Comment: `var digital = new Date(2016, 12, 20, 17, 57, 45, 0);`

Comment: Os meses começam a contar de 0, veja a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Já li essa documentação, mas não consegui entender o que deve ser alterado exatamente para ser exibido a data correta...

Comment: Devo alterar na variável digital?